# TransactionScope performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, transactionscope

I have performance issues when using TransactionScope class in my server side code (WCF).

My code gets request from client, creates TransactionScope and performs short operations (usually up to 100 ms).

See bellow the attached code that simulates my server side code. The problem that when there are 100 and more concurrent users, it takes more then 1 second !!! to create new TransactionScope (see GetTransaction() method).

And when it goes up to 200 concurrent users, TransactionAborted is thrown .

Do you have any ideas?

```
class Program
     {
         private static ConcurrentQueue<double> m_Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<double>();

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start ...");
         Console.ReadKey();

         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
             Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method));
             t.IsBackground = true;
             t.Start();
         }

         Thread.Sleep(2000);
         Console.WriteLine("Max {0}, Min {1}, Avg {2}, Total {3}", m_Queue.Max(), m_Queue.Min(), m_Queue.Average(), m_Queue.Count);
         Console.ReadKey();
     }


     private static void Method() 
     {
         using (TransactionScope scope = GetTransaction())
         {
             Thread.Sleep(100);
             scope.Complete();
         }
     }

     public static TransactionScope GetTransaction()
     {
         var start = DateTime.Now;

         TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
         options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
         var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options);

         // Log creation time
         m_Queue.Enqueue((DateTime.Now.Subtract(start)).TotalMilliseconds);

         return t;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Initial answer:

If I test it with a simple List instead of a ConcurrentQueue (I don't have .net 4.5 installed), your code works fine on my end.

Since you start 200 threads at the same time, your line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Max {0}, Min {1}, Avg {2}, Total {3}", m_Queue.Max(), m_Queue.Min(), m_Queue.Average(), m_Queue.Count);
```

basically starts to iterate over the queue, which blocks the queue, and this causes the still-starting-threads to freeze when trying to add the item to the queue, and in turn causes a time-out in the transaction.

Can you try it without the above mentioned console-writeline?
Also, try it with a normal list.

A solution would be to wait for the threads to finish before you try to perform the max/min/avg/total functions.

One thing to notice is that the total I get in my test, is not the full 100 or 200. It is just a little below, which means there are still threads starting up.

### Update:

If it helps. Any problems I have are solved if I move the enqueue call up in the method. Would that work in your situation?

```
public static TransactionScope GetTransaction() {
    var start = DateTime.Now;

    // Log creation time
    m_Queue.Enqueue((DateTime.Now.Subtract(start)).TotalMilliseconds);

    TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
    options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options);

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Can't use a list, since the queue is being accessed on multiple threads.

Comment: The problem (incorrectly) indicated is the transactionscope, but I think the problem lies with the concurrent queue, since that halts the executing of threads, which in turn causes the problems with the transactionscope. Fix the problem, not the side-effect.

Comment: You're not actually fixing the problem, you're creating a new one.  The concurrent queue halts *some* execution of the threads, when there is a contention.  There's also overhead because it has to check to see if there is contention.  Removing that check will lead to corrupted data.  You're swapping out one problem for another.  Concurrent access is a *must* in this situation.

Comment: Ok, but unfortunately the current way to enforce the concurrent access leads to an exception when using transactionscopes. And if the OP mentioned the requirement for the concurrent access, then we would know as well. It is not mentioned in the original question. Fact remains, if you block the execution of a thread when a transaction is in play, that it can lead to problems.

Comment: I would think the 100 threads accessing the queue would make the requirement for concurrency implicit...

Comment: I found that the exceptions go away when you move the enqueue line up in the method (see my updated answer). Would that work in your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your "enqueue" line, see if the problem persists.

Another thing, I'm curious about the "short operations" being executed within the transaction scope. they might be escalating the transaction coordinator from LTM to MSDTC, which might explain the slowness with more concurrent hits.